# Agregar campo Many2one - Odoo

Tags: odoo, relaciones

Necesito ayuda en Odoo, quiero utilizar un campo Many2one para seleccionar el laboratorio correspondiente al momento de registrar medicamentos.

Tengo dos modelos creados, Medicamentos y Laboratorios. Cada medicamento debe tener su laboratorio asociado.

El problema es que luego de crear dicho campo, solo me muestra el nombre del modelo y la ID del laboratorio previamente registrado, yo necesito que me muestre el nombre del medicamento.

Adjunto imagen de referencia:

[image: Imagen de referencia]

**Actualización, agrego codigo de la seccion donde se encuentra el campo Laboratorio el cual es Many2one**

```
<data>
  <xpath expr="//form[1]/sheet[1]/notebook[1]" position="replace">
    <div class="oe_chatter" name="studio_div_5ac2d8">
      <field name="message_follower_ids"/>
      <field name="activity_ids"/>
      <field name="message_ids"/>
    </div>
  </xpath>
  <xpath expr="//field[@name='x_name']" position="replace"/>
  <xpath expr="//field[@name='x_studio_currency_id']" position="after">
    <field name="id"/>
    <field name="x_studio_principio_activo" string="Principio Activo" required="1"/>
    <field name="x_studio_marca" string="Marca"/>
    <field name="x_studio_presentacin" string="Presentación" required="1"/>
    **<field name="x_studio_laboratorio" string="Laboratorio"/>
  </xpath>**
  <xpath expr="//field[@name='x_studio_value']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="required">1</attribute>
    <attribute name="string">Precio (c/imp.)</attribute>
  </xpath>
  <xpath expr="//field[@name='x_studio_value']" position="after">
    <field name="x_studio_moneda" string="Moneda" required="1"/>
    <field name="x_studio_registrado" string="Registrado"/>
    <field name="write_date" string="Ultima actualización"/>
  </xpath>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

parece que creaste el campo Laboratorio de tipo Reference y por eso te sale asi, porque los valores de un campo reference se muestran asi, o quizas algo no quedo bien definido como Many2one y te lo esta sacando como Reference.

** Update

Otra posibilidad muy real es que como creaste el modelo con Odoo Studio y no tienes un campo nombre o algo que se pueda usar para identificar a los registros en ese modelo se genera automaticamente en el name_get esa forma de identificar al registro. Aca lo puedes ver en el codigo de Odoo

```py
    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        result = []
        name = self._rec_name
        if name in self._fields:
            convert = self._fields[name].convert_to_display_name
            for record in self:
                result.append((record.id, convert(record[name], record)))
        else:
            for record in self:
                result.append((record.id, "%s,%s" % (record._name, record.id)))

        return result
```

Es por esto que se ven los registros como `nombre del modelo,el id` porque es el nombre que les genera el name_get.

Para resolverlo intenta ponerle al modelo ese de Laboratorio un campo `name` o `x_name` o `display_name` para que lo asuma como display_name de los registros, creo que te permitira ponerle `x_name` y en ese campo pones el valor que quieres que salga en el many2one

Comment: Hola Aekis.dev, gracias por colaborar, tu respuesta incluye una pregunta y eso no está bien visto por la comunidad, creo que más que una respuesta, es un comentario, te sugiero que la elimines y la agregues como tal, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, saludos!.

Comment: Es correcto, incluye una pregunta debido a que la pregunta original esta un poco incompleta pero da una respuesta a su pregunta asumiendo la situacion mas probable. Igual aca salgo como nuevo colaborador porque no salen los puntos de otros sitios como el principal de stackoverflow donde tenemos casi los mismos puntos y ya se como funciona el sitio y no creo que sea de la forma en la que indicas. Saludos

Comment: Maestro, no cuestiono tu capacidad, ni la valía de tu respuesta, solo te aviso lo que puedes esperar en este sitio, es tu decisión que hacer, por eso solo hice una sugerencia, saludos!!

Comment: Hola, respeto a tu pregunta, lo cree con Odoo Studio directamente con las opciones que da la aplicación, no utilice lineas de codigo. Quizas se puede modificar de alguna manera con codigo pero no he encontrado dicha solución. Gracias!

Comment: Intenta cambiar el tipo de campo, que como te comentaba le pusiste probablemente Reference en lugar de Many2one

Comment: En realidad, en el tipo de campo me figura Many2one, no es ese el problema. Tampoco sé como abrir la vista del codigo de la aplicacion, quizas de ese modo logre llegar al error. Estoy utilizando Odoo Studio online

Comment: No tienes ningun desarrollador que pueda mirarlo?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar, agregue algo de codigo que encontré de la seccion en problemas

Comment: Toca revisar que se te genero en la base de datos para ese campo. Intente reproducir tu problema y no pude, como que no me saca la información que se muestra ahí como valor de un campo reference

Comment: Hola de nuevo, aca estaba revisando codigo de Odoo 16 cuando me tope con algo que me recordo tu caso y debe ser lo que esta pasando aca. Dejame actualizo la respuesta para agregar ese escenario